# I have to put the commands below each time in grub command line to be able to boot

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub

These are the commands  that i have to put each time to be able to boot to my PC

```
set prefix=(hd2,gpt2)/boot/grub
set prefix=(hd2,gpt2)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

after entering the last command (which is `normal`) and pressing enter, it boots to my normal grub boot screen but i have to go through this problem each time. I am dual booting with windows btw and my grub screen shows my windows entry to boot to too.

**OS**: KDE Neon dual booting with Windows 10

**Drives**: One SSD with Windows and the boot partition on it (has multiple partitions one of which is named "Windows" and another one named "boot". This partition is mounted at `/boot/efi`).

Another SSD with the KDE Neon installation on it (has three partitions).

An extra HDD with nothing related to either OSes on it (has only one partition named Silo).

```
$ blkid
```

```
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Silo" UUID="8422C8D922C8D0FA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="c5a43b2c-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Linux-home" UUID="1550c39c-9de8-4e61-969d-865c780c868d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7b0d1cdb-1dae-3945-a79b-e83a705c8266"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Linux-root" UUID="d192bb16-21dc-4869-9fc5-b55784395019" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="841e9e09-7cf1-f341-a0b9-44ecf0e52f96"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="swap" UUID="f97e3903-5274-42da-9afe-de3fffee290a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0a7e4737-0e85-1645-918c-76394dcc306f"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="C687-044C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="adac6d45-5e0c-4e09-a762-bde5a9e9ccb3"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="6A04824A048218E9" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="46b6360d-c785-4392-92a5-ad4b5944e496"
/dev/sda4: UUID="FE28C23628C1EE29" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2169d3ac-bd33-4e03-83b3-178875c68f29"
```

**What I have already tried:**

Running `sudo update-grub`

Using boot-repair

Comment: Post link to Summary Report from Boot Repair. Do not run autofix with multiple drives.

Comment: wher do i find it?

Comment: Use Ubuntu live installer. Add Boot-Repair with ppa per this link. And click on button for on-line report. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rWKHn0bv
Here got it @oldfred

Comment: That when you manually boot and have to use hd2, not hd1 seems wrong. But would be if you have an USB drive still plugged in. My system promotes a USB drive to hd0, changing every other drive up one. But grub should be using UUID which looks correct. UEFI uses GUID of ESP and then a 3 line grub.cfg (line 228 in report) in ESP configfiles to full grub in your install.  You may be able to manually boot with `configfile (hd2,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` Do not know Neon, only Ubuntu. But I might try using Boot-Repair's advanced mode and full reinstall of grub.